# This code isn't working. (Trying to declare array values in a for loop and do math functions on them)

Tags: shell-script

I was again bored and looked up a list of programs to make in bash, and I'm trying to make a CC (credit card) validator. I had to split the characters into an array to do the validation, and I think I did something wrong. I'm not very good at coding, so I really don't understand what I did wrong with the code.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
getchecknumber(){ # get the last digit of the cc number
    str=$1
    checknum=$(echo {str: -1})
}
getrest(){ # get the rest of the numbers in the sequence
    sequence=$(echo {str%?})
}
doubleeveryother(){ # double every other number
    # split characters into an array
    arr=()
    i=0
    while [ "$i" -lt "${#str}" ]; do 
    arr+=(${str:$i:1})
     i=$((i+1))
done
for ((i=1; i<=15; i++))
    do {
        char=$(echo "$i-1" | bc)
        double=$(echo "${arr[$char]} * 2" | bc)
        if (( $i % 2 == 0 )) ; then #check if number is 'every other' (divisible by 2)
            foo=bar #do nothing
        else
            arr[$char]=$double #replace the number in the array
        fi
        }
    done
}
adddigitsum() { #split a two digit number into two numbers and add them
    NUMSPLIT=(0 0)
    for ((a=0; a<=14; a++))
    do {
        number=$(echo ${arr[$a]})
        if ((number>=10)) ; then
            for ((b=0; b<=1; b++))
            do
                NUMSPLIT[$b]=$( echo ${number:$n:1} )
            done
            addeddigit=$( echo "${NUMSPLIT[0]} + ${NUMSPLIT[1]}" | bc )
            arr[$a]=$addeddigit # replace the number in the array
        fi
        }
    done
}
addall(){ #add all the digits
    sum=$( IFS="+"; bc <<< "${arr[*]}" )
}
multiply(){ #multiply by 9
    result=$( echo "$sum * 9" | bc )
}
validate(){ #see if the last number of 'result' is equal to the checknum
    resultchecknum=$(echo {string%?})
    if [[ $resultchecknum == $checknum ]] ; then
        echo "CC Number is valid!"
    else
        echo "CC Number is not valid."
    fi
}

getchecknumber
getrest
doubleeveryother
adddigitsum
addall
multiply
validate
```

Output:

```
./cc-validator.sh 4000000000000000
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
CC Number is not valid.
```

Comment: Before you can get the checknumber shouldn't you read it in from the standard input?  `$1` is the first argument passed in the command line, but if the program never received one it cant parse,  hence the error.  Try `./scriptname CCNUMBER`

Comment: @eyoung100 I do use an argument with a CC number. I just didn't put that in the output segment. I probably should.

Comment: @eyoung100 Put the argument in the output section (FYI: that number was randomly generated)

Comment: OK I updated your post to include a "fake CC" number.  Try adding `echo $1` to `getchecknumber()` before you `echo str -1` to see if what you put in is what comes out

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I just realized that I was putting everything in functions, so I forgot I had to use the function with $1 as well (using `function $1` in the code)